# PHP mail() script is sending me unwanted emails

Tags: php, email

I have a simple PHP mailer script and it is sending me an email everyday as if someone has clicked the submit button without any inputs (blank email).  Is there a way to suppress this behavior?  What should I change in my script?  Thanks

```
$message = $_POST[message];
$name = $_POST[name];
$email = $_POST[email];
$email_message = $name ."  has sent you a message: \n" . $message . "\n Please contact " . $name . " with \n Email: " . $email . "\n Phone: " . $phone;

echo "Hi " .$name ."<br> Your Email is: " .$email ."<br><br>And we     received the following message: <br>" . $message."<br><a href='../index.html'>Back Home</a>";

mail($to, $subject, $email_message);

?>
```

Comment: Check that `$_POST[message]` is set, or that it isn't empty.

Comment: Validate input before sending out email by using empty().

Comment: so would something like this will suppress the blank emails?:
if(!empty($_POST[message]){ mail($to, $subject, $email_message);}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$message = $_POST[message];   
$name = $_POST[name];    
$email = $_POST[email];

$email_message = $name ."  has sent you a message: \n" . $message . "\n Please contact " . $name . " with \n Email: " . $email . "\n Phone: " . $phone;

echo "Hi " .$name ." < break tag > Your Email is: " .$email ." < break tag > And we     received the following message: < break tag > " . $message." < break tag > <a href='../index.html'>Back Home</a>";

if(isset($_POST[message]) && isset($_POST[name]) && isset($_POST[email]))
{
   mail($to, $subject, $email_message);

} else{
   echo "Error";

}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @AlejandroIván You are right ..! But it could be a alternative methinks ...!

Answer (score 1):

Check if the values are empty or not before sending the mail:

```
// Check if values exist before continuing
if ( 
    isset($_POST['message']) && strlen($_POST['message']) > 0
    &&
    isset($_POST['name']) && strlen($_POST['name']) > 0
    &&
    isset($_POST['email']) && strlen($_POST['email']) > 0
)
{
    $message = $_POST['message']; // Remember to use single or double quotes!!!!
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $email_message = $name ."  has sent you a message: \n" . $message . "\n Please contact " . $name . " with \n Email: " . $email . "\n Phone: " . $phone;

    echo "Hi " .$name ."<br> Your Email is: " .$email ."<br><br>And we     received the following message: <br>" . $message."<br><a href='../index.html'>Back Home</a>";

    mail($to, $subject, $email_message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check whether the values that you are about to send are set or not and submit button is clicked.

**Sample Form** (form.php)

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="text" name="email" />
  <textarea name="message"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

**Callback Page** (submit.php)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   // Your code comes here
   // you can use conditions to validate the form
   // ex:  if(!empty($_POST['message'])) or if(trim($_POST['message']) != "") to avoid empty message submissions
   // Regular expressions to validate email addresses / name
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so - the problem is that you're not checking wether or not the fields has been filled, so we're doing that and if they haven't filled out all fields, redirect them back to the contact page with something telling why it made an error. Additionally, we're storing the fields temporarily to avoid issues with users have to fill out all fields again, in case they did fill some out.

```
<?php
session_start(); // For remembering input (please remember to put this before any output)

$message = $_POST[message];
$name = $_POST[name];
$email = $_POST[email];

if( empty($message) || empty($name) || empty($email) )
{
    // Redirect back to contact page, but use sessions to remember already filled out fields
    $_SESSION['contact_form']['message'] = $message;
    $_SESSION['contact_form']['name'] = $name;
    $_SESSION['contact_form']['email'] = $email;

     header("Location: http://example.com/contact_page");
    exit; // Make sure the rest of the script isn't completed
}

if(isset($_SESSION['contact_form'])) // Check if cleaning up is needed
{
    unset($_SESSION['contact_form']); //No need to store this after we send the mail
}

$email_message = $name ."  has sent you a message: \n\n"; 
$email_message .= "Please contact " . $name . " with \n Email: " . $email . "\n";
$email_message .= "Phone: " . $phone;

mail($to, $subject, $email_message, "From: youremail@example.com\r\n"); // added a sender header, just for best practices

?>

Hi <?php echo $name; ?><br>
Your Email is: <?php echo $email; ?><br><br>
And we received the following message: <br>
<?php echo $message; ?><br>
<a href='../index.html'>Back Home</a>
```

Now, that being done, we need to consider the contact page again, because now we need to tell them that an error occurred and fill out the contact fields again, for those fields thet did fill.

```
<?php
session_start(); // For fetching remembered output input (please remember to put this before any output)

$error = ;
$message = $name = $email = "";
if(isset($_SESSION['contact_form']))
{
    $error = true;
    $message = $_SESSION['contact_form']['message'];
    $name = $_SESSION['contact_form']['name'];
    $email = $_SESSION['contact_form']['email'];

    unset($_SESSION['contact_form']); // In case they just leave
}

?>


<?php if($error): ?>
<p class="error">You missed some fields, could you please fill them out?</p>
<?php endif; ?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
    <textarea name="message"><?php echo $message; ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I hope this can give you an idea of some workflow and combining with a little user experience.

Answer (score 0):

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$email_message = $name ."  has sent you a message: \n" . $message . "\n Please contact " . $name . " with \n Email: " . $email . "\n Phone: " . $phone;

echo "Hi " .$name ."<br> Your Email is: " .$email ."<br><br>And we     received the following message: <br>" . $message."<br><a href='../index.html'>Back Home</a>";

if(!empty($message) && !empty($name) && !empty($email)) {
    mail($to, $subject, $email_message);
}
```

I did not include $email_message because it won't be empty from the start since you're assembling it above.

Answer (score 0):

$subject = 'Subject line for emails';

$headers = 'From: Email Tital ' . "\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$message = "Your Message"\n\r";

$sentMail = @mail($to_Email, $subject, $message, $headers);

if(!$sentMail) {

```
echo "Server error, could not send email. Sorry for the inconvenience." ;
```

} else {

echo "Thank you for enquiry. We will contact you shortly !";

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to check first message field is empty or not,its client site check if you press submit without message it never submit your form,

```
function empty() {
    var x;
    x = document.getElementById("message").value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Enter a message first");
        return false;
    };
}
```

and

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="return empty()" />
```